# Need to rewrite some code

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, swift

This code works fine:

```
var x = 3.14
var y: Double

switch true {

case (x<=0.5):
    y = 0.5
    println(y)

case x>-0.5 && x<=0:
    y = x + 1
    println(y)

case x>0 && x<=1:
    y = x*x-1
    println(y)

case x>1:
    y = x - 1
    println(y)
default: println()
}
```

How could I rewrite this code to get the same result? I have bugs in lines with `case x>..1:` and `case x>..1:`

```
var x: 3.14
var y: Double

switch x {

case >..0.5:
    y = 0.5
    println(y)

case -0.5...0:
    y = x + 1
    println(y)
case 0<..1:
    y = x*x-1
    println(y)

case x>..1:
    y = x - 1
    println(y)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am assuming that your first two cases should actually be `x <= -0.5`
and `-0.5 < x <= 1.0`, otherwise the second case would never be true.)

You *could* use a `switch` statement:

```
switch x {
case -DBL_MAX ... -0.5:
// Or: case let t where t <= -0.5:
    y = 0.5
case -0.5 ... 0.0:
    y = x + 1
case 0.0 ... 1.0:
    y = x*x - 1
default:
    y = x - 1
}
println(y)
```

Since the first matching case is used, it does not matter that
the starting value is included in the second and third case.

If the last value of the range should *not* be included in a case
then you can use `HalfOpenInterval` instead:

```
switch x {
case HalfOpenInterval(-DBL_MAX, -0.5):
    y = 0.5
case HalfOpenInterval(-0.5, 0):
    y = x + 1
case HalfOpenInterval(0.0, 1.0):
    y = x*x - 1
default:
    y = x - 1
}
println(y)
```

But I probably would just use `if/else if/else`:

```
if x <= -0.5 {
    y = 0.5
} else if x <= 0.0 {
    y = x + 1
} else if (x <= 1.0) {
    y = x*x - 1
} else {
    y = x - 1
}
println(y)
```

or a nested conditional expression:

```
let y = x <= -0.5   ? 0.5 :
        x <= 0.0    ? x + 1 :
        x <= 1.0    ? x * x - 1 :
                    x - 1
println(y)
```

Comment: also, `(-DBL_MAX ... -0.5).contains(Double.NaN)` is `true`, which might lead to some fun bugs when using the `switch` version.

Comment: I had to solve the problem with switch, thank you for your solution!

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: That problem seems not to be restricted to the switch-version. `Double.NaN <= -0.5` is also `true` (but `Double.NaN < -0.5` is `false`)

Comment: How could I include starting value in the second and third case.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting, wonder if this is because `Double` (unlike the different integers) doesn't have its own `<=`, it uses the one that comes from `Double` conforming to `Comparable` which requires strict total ordering that `Double`'s `<` doesn't provide.

Comment: @user3765444: See updated answer, I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: I just double-checked with Xcode 6.3 beta 4, and now `Double.NaN <= -0.5`, `Double.NaN < -0.5` and `(-DBL_MAX ... -0.5).contains(Double.NaN)` all return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The second case makes no sense:

```
case x>=0.5 && x<=0:
```

This can never be true. A value cannot be greater than 0.5 and smaller or equal to zero.

Comment: I wrote "=" instead of "-". I corrected it, thank you.